# Programming tutorials that do not use an IDE (C# & C++)

Tags: c#, c++, assembly

well the title pretty much explains the core of my question.

I have been unable to locate a tutorial/Tutorials for C# and C++ (I would like to find one for C# but C++ would be appreciated as well)

that encourage you to not use an IDE of any type, tutorials that make you learn EVERYTHING the old/hard way.
Im wanting to find tutorials that teach you to use only notepad or something similar, I dont want to depend on drag n drop and i feel like i will be learning so much more on how things work. So with that said does anyone know of such tutorials/books/websites?

I appreciate any assistance on this, Everyone have a great day

Comment: Why? Not using an IDE doesn't make you a better programmer..

Comment: I take offense at that "the old way" remark... :-S

Comment: "i feel like i will be learning so much more on how things work" No.

Comment: Realizing what happens when you compile something vs link it can be useful, but other than that, it's usually more a waste of time.

Comment: Tutorials for Linux (for one example) are a lot more likely to assume you'll use something like vim, and do the compiling at the command line.

Comment: @chris: It's also nice if you're collaborating with other people. Everyone can have their own setup, but a grasp of the essentials allows you to adapt to any situation.

Comment: Drag and drop? What do you think IDEs are? Hypercard?

Comment: You've drawn an arbitrary line in the sand. Most tutorials aren't written this way for the same reason that medical students aren't taught basic anatomy in the middle of a battlefield. One thing at a time. Learn the idiosyncrasies of the language (and let the IDE hold your hand). Once you've done this and feel comfortable with the language, then learn how to run the compiler from the command line. Then find an editor and spend a while learning it. Then learn about makefiles and scripts. Then tie it all together. Or change the order around. Do you see that this is too big for any one tutorial?

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not appropriate here ("please post a list of links for me"). There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really looking for, is a tutorial that focuses on *code* and not *wizards and graphical spaghetti wire designers*.  When working with code, you'll want a good programmers' editor that does syntax highlighting and jump to definition and so on.  Unfortunately, the term "Integrated Development Environment" is overloaded to mean both "good source-level editor and debugger UI" and also "ridiculously abstracted drag-and-drop rapid application wizard".

Comment: Work through http://projecteuler.net/ problems in VS Express IDE - no amount of "drag-n-drop" will help or even be necessary...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of looking for tutorials that explain how to do things without IDE's, you should look for tutorials that explain how to compile from the command line. You can then use notepad (or emacs or VIM or w/e text editor you want) and follow along with the "IDE tutorials." But I agree with most people here, you might as well use an IDE. Most of them don't "hide" things from you that you need to concern yourself with anyways.

Comment: thank you everyone for the input, But its just what im looking for, I just want to see everything behind the scenes, i dont want an ide taking shortcut's for me.

Comment: +1. `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe CodeFileName.cs` is all you need to know to compile C# code... It is very hard to make any significant tutorial of this single line - so it is unlikely to find one.

Answer (score 2):

Why losing time when today, after years, we have some good IDEs that help us to speed up our dead times?

Anyway if you are going to learn a new programmation language,you must know how it works,indipendently on how ("old style") you reach the result.
Start looking for tutorials that explain how to compile from the command line.

Comment: Thank you everyone, all your input is helpful. But im also wanting to make sure i know how to create my own windows,buttons ect, do you get what i mean? i think i will do what you guys suggest, but for some reason i just feel like im cheating myself

Comment: Start learning how to run the compiler from the command line.It takes some hours.When you practice with it find an IDE and spend a while learning it,and choose the one you want (I see you tagged c++ and c#,so try out Qt Creator and Visual Studio). Its a lot of work to do.If you don't wanna cheat,start doing programs with with punch cards! (I'm joking)